# Identifying where value changes in R data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` in R where the `value` column contains data of the class `character`. I want to identify the row numbers where `value` changes. In the example below I want to get out 4, 7, and 9. Is there a way to do this without looping?

```
df <- data.frame(ind=1:10,
 value=as.character(c(100,100,100,200,200,200,300,300,400,400)), 
 stringsAsFactors=F)
df
   ind value
1    1   100
2    2   100
3    3   100
4    4   200
5    5   200
6    6   200
7    7   300
8    8   300
9    9   400
10  10   400
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the lag function in dplyr:

```
which(df$value != dplyr::lag(df$value))
```

Answer (score 12):

Similar to @thc's answer, but without a dependency:

```
which(c(FALSE, tail(df$value,-1) != head(df$value,-1)))
#[1] 4 7 9
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `rle` (Run Length Encoding):

```
cumsum(rle(df$value)$lengths)+1
[1]  4  7  9 11
```

You can use `head` to drop the last value:

```
head(cumsum(rle(df$value)$lengths)+1, -1)
```

Comment: You need to drop the last value.