# How to determine when a change in value occurs in R

Tags: r

I am following this example from stack overflow: [Identifying where value changes in R data.frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154687/identifying-where-value-changes-in-r-data-frame-column)

Theres two columns: ind and value. How do I identify the 'ind' when 'value' increases by 100?

For example,
Value increases by 100 at ind = 4.

```
df <- data.frame(ind=1:10,
value=as.character(c(100,100,100,200,200,200,300,300,400,400)), stringsAsFactors=F)
df

        ind value
    1    1   100
    2    2   100
    3    3   100
    4    4   200
    5    5   200
    6    6   200
    7    7   300
    8    8   300
    9    9   400
    10  10   400
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 miss <- function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x),x,NA)
 value_xx   =miss(min(df$ind[df$value[1:length(df$value)] >= 100], Inf, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Why `as.character` on `value` ?

Comment: im just following the example given from the other stack overflow question. I guess it should be as.numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
df$ind[c(FALSE, diff(as.numeric(df$value)) == 100)]
```

Comment: it works when I try for 100, but when I increase to 200 (df$ind[c(FALSE, diff(as.numeric(df$value)) == 200)]) I get integer(0)

Comment: because between two consecutive rows you dont have any step worth 200. You need to clarify your question then...

Comment: Oh.. How to you compare it to the first row? (i.e. what is the 'ind' where 'value' increase by 200 compared to the first row of 'value'?)

Comment: Given `df <- data.frame(ind=1:10, value=c(100,100,100,200,200,200,300,300,400,400))`, the answer would be: `df$ind[(df$value - df$value[1]) == 200]`

Comment: and if you need only the first one: `df$ind[which((df$value - df$value[1]) == 200)[1]]`. However, these are rather specific answers.. maybe you're looking for something more generic..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` to get difference between consecutive values and get the index for those where the difference is greater than equal to 100. Added `+ 1` to the index since `diff` returns vector which of length 1 shorter than the original one.

```
df$ind[which(diff(df$value) >= 100) + 1]
#[1] 4 7 9
```

In `dplyr`, you can use `lag` to get previous values :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(value - lag(value) >= 100)

#  ind value
#1   4   200
#2   7   300
#3   9   400
```

Comment: df$ind[which(diff(df$value) >= 100) + 1] this works when im only trying to see where it increases by 100. When I change this to 200 I get integer(0) instead of '7'. Can this not be extended to look at other changes compared to the first value (ind=1, value=100)?

Comment: @LR55 If you need to compare with first value do `df$ind[df$value - df$value[1] >= 200]`