# Find cumulative value change and time since last change in panel data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, panel-data, tapply

I have panel data (small example of data below), and want to calculate both when a variable changes as well as the time from the last change. The end goal is to get two variables: cumulative change in any given year (i.e. the difference between the current value and the starting value), and the time since the last change.

```
# example data
structure(list(rcode = c("DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE1", "DE1", 
                         "DE1", "DE1", "DE2", "DE2", "DE2", "DE2", "DE2", "DE2", "DE2", 
                         "DE2", "DE2", "DE2", "DE2"), 
               n_RAI = c(34.47871, 34.91596, 34.91596, 34.88745, 34.79049, 34.79049, 
                         34.79049, 35.48414, 35.98985, 35.98985, 36.98985, 34.47871, 
                         34.91596, 34.91596, 34.88745, 34.79049, 34.79049, 34.79049, 
                         35.48414, 35.98985, 35.98985, 36.98985), 
               year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
                        2009L, 2010L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
                        2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L)), 
           row.names = 375:396, class = "data.frame")
```

In this data, `r_code` is individual identifier, `n_RAI` is the variable I'm trying to lag, and `year` is the time variable.

It's fairly simple to identify when a change occurred for each individual in the panel, using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154687/identifying-where-value-changes-in-r-data-frame-column).

Where I'm struggling is to come up with a function that, using `dplyr::group_by` or `tapply` to apply across individuals in the panel, can also calculate the time since the last change. Essentially, I need a function that identifies when a change occurs, starts counting upwards moving forwards, then resets when another change occurs. It seems simple, but I've hit some mental block and can't think of how to translate that into R. Is there a function out there or a simple base R way of doing this that I'm failing to see?

e.g. the expected output for individual DE1, using "change" as a variable name for identifying a change and "t_since" as the time from the last change:

```
change = 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
t_since = 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2
```

Comment: @GregorThomas - whoops, that's the indicator for an individual. I'll change the text thanks.

Comment: @arg0naut91 expected output added to question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works. It's a little convoluted. The `t_since` result matches your desired result, the `change` column is a little different than what you show in the question, but I think that might be a typo in your question. (Calling your data `dd`.)

```
dd = dd %>%
  group_by(rcode) %>%
  mutate(
    change = c(0, abs(diff(n_RAI)) > 1e-8),
    grouper = (cumsum(change) - 1) %/% 2
  ) %>%
  group_by(rcode, grouper) %>%
  mutate(t_since = pmax(0, 0:(n() - 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grouper)

change = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
t_since = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2)

dd = cbind(dd, goal_change = change, goal_t_since = t_since)

all(dd$goal_change == dd$change)
# [1] FALSE
all(dd$goal_t_since == dd$t_since)
# [1] TRUE
```